# Data mining in Java: finding undrawn lottery rows - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, data-mining

(See the [previous (initial) iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58360/coderodde).)

This time, I have substantially reduced the usage of the `final` and `this` keywords. Also, I have dropped `java.util.(SortedMap/TreeMap)` and substituted it with a simple hash table/array, which dropped the running time of the mining phase by half:

```
Seed = 1588247737638
Data generated in 22773 milliseconds.
Duration: 51508 milliseconds.
Missing lottery rows: 2182644
```

**Code**

**`net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.LotteryConfiguration.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.datamining.lottery;

/**
 * This class specifies the lottery game configuration.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 18, 2020)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 18, 2020)
 */
public class LotteryConfiguration {

    /**
     * The maximum ball integer value.
     */
    private final int maximumNumberValue;

    /**
     * The length of each lottery row.
     */
    private final int lotteryRowLength;

    /**
     * Construct a new lottery configuration.
     * 
     * @param maximumNumberValue the maximum ball integer value.
     * @param lotteryRowLength   the lottery row length.
     */
    public LotteryConfiguration(final int maximumNumberValue,
                                final int lotteryRowLength) {
        checkArgs(maximumNumberValue, lotteryRowLength);
        this.maximumNumberValue = maximumNumberValue;
        this.lotteryRowLength   = lotteryRowLength;
    }

    public int getMaximumNumberValue() {
        return this.maximumNumberValue;
    }

    public int getLotteryRowLength() {
        return this.lotteryRowLength;
    }

    private static void checkArgs(int maximumNumber, int numberCount) {
        if (maximumNumber < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "maximumNumber(" + maximumNumber + ") < 1");
        }

        if (numberCount < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "numberCount(" + numberCount + ") < 1");
        }

        if (numberCount > maximumNumber) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "numberCount(" + numberCount + ") > " + 
                    "maximumNumber(" + maximumNumber + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

**`net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.LotteryRow.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.datamining.lottery;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a single lottery row.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremove
 * @version 1.61 (Apr 27, 2020) ~ removed manual sorting.
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 18, 2020) ~ initial version.
 * @since 1.6 (Apr 18, 2020)
 */
public class LotteryRow {

    /**
     * The configuration object.
     */
    private final LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration;

    /**
     * The actual lottery numbers.
     */
    private final int[] lotteryNumbers;

    /**
     * Stores the index of the internal storage array at which the next lottery
     * number will be inserted.
     */
    private int size = 0;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty lottery row with given configuration.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery row configuration.
     */
    public LotteryRow(LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration) {
        this.lotteryConfiguration = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(lotteryConfiguration);

        this.lotteryNumbers =
                new int[lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength()];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFirst = true;

        for (final int number : this.lotteryNumbers) {
            if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
                stringBuilder.append(number);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(",").append(number);
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Appends a number to the tail of this lottery row.
     * 
     * @param number the number to append.
     */
    public void appendNumber(int number) {
        checkNumber(number);
        checkHasSpaceForNewNumber();
        lotteryNumbers[size++] = number;
        Arrays.sort(lotteryNumbers, 0, size);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <code>index</code>th number.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the desired number.
     * @return the <code>index</code>th number.
     */
    public int getNumber(int index) {
        checkIndex(index);
        return lotteryNumbers[index];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the configuration object of this row.
     * 
     * @return the configuration object.
     */
    public LotteryConfiguration getLotteryConfiguration() {
        return lotteryConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * Checks that there is more space for lottery numbers in this row.
     */
    private void checkHasSpaceForNewNumber() {
        if (size == lotteryNumbers.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The lottery row cannot accommodate more numbers.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input number is within the lottery number range.
     * 
     * @param number the number to check.
     */
    private void checkNumber(int number) {
        if (number < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number(" + number + ") < 1");
        }

        if (number > this.lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "number (" + number + ") > " +
                "this.lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue()[" +
                this.lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue() + "]");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the index is withing the range <code>[0, n)</code>.
     * 
     * @param index the index to check.
     */
    private void checkIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index(" + index + ") < 0");
        }

        if (index >= this.size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "index(" + index + ") >= this.index(" + this.size + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

**`net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.LotteryRowGenerator.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.datamining.lottery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements a facility for creating random lottery rows.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov 
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 18, 2020) 
 * @since 1.6 (Apr 18, 2020)
 */
public final class LotteryRowGenerator {

    /**
     * The lottery configuration object.
     */
    private final LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration;

    /**
     * The random number generator.
     */
    private final Random random;

    /**
     * The storage array for.
     */
    private final int[] numbers;

    /**
     * Constructs a {@code LotteryRowGenerator} with a given configuration.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery configuration object.
     */
    public LotteryRowGenerator(LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration) {
        this(lotteryConfiguration, new Random());
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a {@code LotteryRowGenerator} with a given configuration and
     * a seed value.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery configuration object.
     * @param seed the seed value.
     */
    public LotteryRowGenerator(LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration,
                               long seed) {
        this(lotteryConfiguration, new Random(seed));
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a {@code LotteryRowGenerator} with a given configuration and
     * a random number generator.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery configuration object.
     * @param random the random number generator.
     */
    public LotteryRowGenerator(LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration,
                               Random random) {
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random, 
                                             "The input Random is null.");
        this.lotteryConfiguration =
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        lotteryConfiguration,
                        "The input LotteryConfiguration is null.");

        numbers = new int[lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue()];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates and returns a list of random lottery rows.
     * 
     * @param numberOfLotteryRows the requested number of lottery rows.
     * @return a list of random rows.
     */
    public List<LotteryRow> 
        generateLotteryRows(int numberOfLotteryRows) {
        List<LotteryRow> rows = new ArrayList<>(numberOfLotteryRows);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLotteryRows; i++) {
            rows.add(generateRow());
        }

        return rows;
    }

    private LotteryRow generateRow() {
        LotteryRow lotteryRow = new LotteryRow(lotteryConfiguration);
        shuffleInternalNumbers();
        loadLotteryRow(lotteryRow);
        return lotteryRow;
    }

    private void shuffleInternalNumbers() {
        for (int i = 0, n = lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue();
                i < n; 
                i++) {
            swap(i, getRandomIndex());
        }
    }

    public void loadLotteryRow(LotteryRow lotteryRow) {
        for (int i = 0, n = lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength();
                i < n;
                i++) {
            lotteryRow.appendNumber(numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    private int getRandomIndex() {
        return random.nextInt(lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue());
    }

    private void swap(final int index1, final int index2) {
        int tmp = numbers[index1];
        numbers[index1] = numbers[index2];
        numbers[index2] = tmp;
    }
}
```

**`net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.MissingLotteryRowsGenerator.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.datamining.lottery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a data mining algorithm for selecting all possible 
 * lottery rows that do not appear in the given data set. This version differs
 * from {@link net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.MissingLotteryRowsGenerator} in
 * that respect that TreeMaps are changed to lighter unbalanced binary search
 * trees.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 28, 2020) ~ renamed the class.
 * @since 1.6 (Apr 20, 2020)
 */
public final class MissingLotteryRowsGenerator {

    private static final class RadixTreeNode {
        RadixTreeNode[] children;
    }

    private final RadixTreeNode root;
    private final LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration;

    /**
     * Implements the main constructor.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery configuration object.
     * @param root the root node of the radix tree.
     */
    private MissingLotteryRowsGenerator(
            LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration,
            RadixTreeNode root) {

        this.lotteryConfiguration =
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        lotteryConfiguration, 
                        "lotteryConfiguration == null");

        this.root = Objects.requireNonNull(root, "The root node is null.");
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a missing rows generator with given lottery configuration.
     * 
     * @param lotteryConfiguration the lottery configuration.
     */
    public MissingLotteryRowsGenerator(
            LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration) {
        this(lotteryConfiguration, new RadixTreeNode());
    }

    /**
     * Adds a list of lottery rows to this generator.
     * 
     * @param lotteryRows the lottery rows to add one by one.
     * @return this generator for chaining.
     */
    public MissingLotteryRowsGenerator
        addLotteryRows(List<LotteryRow> lotteryRows) {

        for (LotteryRow lotteryRow : lotteryRows) {
            addLotteryRow(lotteryRow);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a single lottery row to this generator.
     * 
     * @param lotteryRow the lottery row to add.
     * @return this generator for chaining.
     */
    public MissingLotteryRowsGenerator
        addLotteryRow(LotteryRow lotteryRow) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(lotteryRow, "lotteryRow == null");
        checkLotteryRow(lotteryRow);
        RadixTreeNode node = root;
        int maximumValue = lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue();

        for (int i = 0, sz = lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength(); 
                i < sz; 
                i++) {
            RadixTreeNode nextNode;
            int number = lotteryRow.getNumber(i);

            if (node.children == null) {
                node.children = new RadixTreeNode[maximumValue];
            }

            if (node.children[number - 1] == null) {
                RadixTreeNode tmp = new RadixTreeNode();
                nextNode = tmp;
                node.children[number - 1] = tmp;

                if (i < sz - 1) {
                    nextNode.children = new RadixTreeNode[maximumValue];
                }
            } else {
                nextNode = node.children[number - 1];
            }

            node = nextNode;
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Computes and returns all the <i>missing</i> lottery rows. A lottery row 
     * is <i>missing</i> if and only if it was not drawn in the population of
     * players.
     * 
     * @return the list of missing lottery rows.
     */
    public List<LotteryRow> computeMissingLotteryRows() {
        List<LotteryRow> lotteryRows = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] numbers = getInitialNumbers();

        do {
            LotteryRow lotteryRow = convertNumbersToLotteryRow(numbers);

            if (!treeContains(lotteryRow)) {
                lotteryRows.add(lotteryRow);
            }

        } while (increment(numbers));

        return lotteryRows;
    }

    private boolean treeContains(LotteryRow lotteryRow) {
        RadixTreeNode node = root;

        for (int i = 0, sz = lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength(); 
                i < sz;
                i++) {

            int number = lotteryRow.getNumber(i);
            RadixTreeNode nextNode = node.children[number - 1];

            if (nextNode == null) {
                return false;
            }

            node = nextNode;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean increment(final int[] numbers) {
        int maximumNumber = lotteryConfiguration.getMaximumNumberValue();
        int lotteryRowLength = lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength();

        for (int i = lotteryRowLength - 1, j = 0; 
                i >= 0; 
                i--, j++) {

            if (numbers[i] < maximumNumber - j) {
                numbers[i]++;

                for (int k = i + 1; k < lotteryRowLength; k++) {
                    numbers[k] = numbers[k - 1] + 1;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a number integer array into a 
     * {@link net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.LotteryRow}.
     * @param numbers the raw number array in ascending order.
     * @return the lottery row with exactly the same numbers as in 
     * {@code numbers}.
     */
    private LotteryRow convertNumbersToLotteryRow(int[] numbers) {
        LotteryRow lotteryRow = new LotteryRow(this.lotteryConfiguration);

        for (int number : numbers) {
            lotteryRow.appendNumber(number);
        }

        return lotteryRow;
    }

    private int[] getInitialNumbers() {
        int lotteryRowLength = lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength();
        int[] numbers = new int[lotteryRowLength];

        for (int i = 0, number = 1; i < lotteryRowLength; i++, number++) {
            numbers[i] = number;
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    private void checkLotteryRow(final LotteryRow lotteryRow) {
        if (lotteryRow.getLotteryConfiguration().getLotteryRowLength()
                != lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Wrong length of a row (" +
                            lotteryRow.getLotteryConfiguration()
                                       .getLotteryRowLength() + 
                            ", must be exactly " + 
                            this.lotteryConfiguration.getLotteryRowLength() + 
                            ".");
        }
    }
}
```

**`net.coderodde.datamining.lottery.Demo.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.datamining.lottery;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the functionality of the missing lottery row data
 * mining algorithm.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 25, 2020)
 * @since 1.6 (Apr 25, 2020)
 */
public final class Demo {

    // 40 choose 7 = 18_643_560 combinations:
    private static final int LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH = 7;
    private static final int LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER = 40;
    private static final int LOTTERY_ROWS = 40_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        smallDemo();

        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration = 
                new LotteryConfiguration(LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER,
                                         LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH);

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        List<LotteryRow> data = benchmarkAndObtainData(seed);
        benchmark(lotteryConfiguration, data);
    }

    private static List<LotteryRow> benchmarkAndObtainData(final long seed) {
        LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration = 
                new LotteryConfiguration(LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER,    
                                         LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH);

        // Warmup run:
        new LotteryRowGenerator(lotteryConfiguration, seed)
                .generateLotteryRows(LOTTERY_ROWS);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // Data generation: 
        List<LotteryRow> data =
                new LotteryRowGenerator(lotteryConfiguration)
                        .generateLotteryRows(LOTTERY_ROWS);

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(
                "Data generated in " + 
                        ((endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000L) + 
                        " milliseconds.");

        return data;
    }

    // Warms up and benchmarks the 
    private static void benchmark(LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration,
                                  List<LotteryRow> data) throws IOException {

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        List<LotteryRow> missingLotteryRows = 
            new MissingLotteryRowsGenerator(lotteryConfiguration)
                .addLotteryRows(data)
                .computeMissingLotteryRows();

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(
                "Duration: " 
                        + ((endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000L) 
                        + " milliseconds.");

        System.out.println(
                "Missing lottery rows: " + missingLotteryRows.size());

//        boolean isFirst = true;
//        
//        for (final LotteryRow lotteryRow : missingLotteryRows) {
//            if (isFirst) {
//                isFirst = false;
//            } else {
//                System.out.println();
//            }
//            
//            System.out.print(lotteryRow);
//        }
    }

    // Runs a small demo:
    private static void smallDemo() {
        LotteryConfiguration lotteryConfiguration = 
                new LotteryConfiguration(5, 3);

        LotteryRow lotteryRow1 = new LotteryRow(lotteryConfiguration); // 1, 2, 4
        LotteryRow lotteryRow2 = new LotteryRow(lotteryConfiguration); // 2, 4, 5
        LotteryRow lotteryRow3 = new LotteryRow(lotteryConfiguration); // 1, 3, 5
        LotteryRow lotteryRow4 = new LotteryRow(lotteryConfiguration); // 3, 4, 5

        lotteryRow1.appendNumber(1);
        lotteryRow1.appendNumber(4);
        lotteryRow1.appendNumber(2);

        lotteryRow2.appendNumber(4);
        lotteryRow2.appendNumber(5);
        lotteryRow2.appendNumber(2);

        lotteryRow3.appendNumber(1);
        lotteryRow3.appendNumber(3);
        lotteryRow3.appendNumber(5);

        lotteryRow4.appendNumber(3);
        lotteryRow4.appendNumber(4);
        lotteryRow4.appendNumber(5);

        List<LotteryRow> drawnLotteryRows = Arrays.asList(lotteryRow1,
                                                          lotteryRow2,
                                                          lotteryRow3,
                                                          lotteryRow4);

        MissingLotteryRowsGenerator generator = 
                new MissingLotteryRowsGenerator(lotteryConfiguration);

        List<LotteryRow> missingLotteryRows = generator
                        .addLotteryRows(drawnLotteryRows)
                        .computeMissingLotteryRows();

        missingLotteryRows.forEach((row) -> { System.out.println(row);});
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I am glad to hear all the comments regarding my Java coding routine. Is there anyting code-/performance wise I could improve?

Comment: I think the calls to `random.nextInt()` will currently take the most time. Can you verify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performance

I tried optimizing it all I could, but it seems calls to `random.next()` really clog things up :(

Ideas:

- Because there are only ~18M valid items, and because 18M < Integer.MAX, we can store them in an array, using the index as ordinal
- Because  `40^7` < Long.MAX, we can store a ticket in a `long`
- We can use binary search on the ordered array of primitive `long`s. Because it is only 18M long, we have a maximum of 25 comparisons to find the index. (or not, if it is not contained). I think a tree might be faster, but if you do not use primitives, you will loose speed in auto-boxing and referencing.

### Source

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FastLottery {

    private static final int LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH = 7;
    private static final int LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER = 40;
    private static final int LOTTERY_ROWS = 40_000_000;
    private static final int OPTIONS = 18643560;


    /* arr[]  ---> Input Array
       data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
       start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
       index  ---> Current index in data[]
       r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
    public static List<int[]> combinationsUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start,
                                               int end, int index, int r)
    {
        List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<>();

        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
        if (index == r)
        {
            int[] result = new int[data.length];
            System.arraycopy(data,0, result,0, data.length);
            results.add(result);
            return results;
        }

        // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
        // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
        // at remaining positions
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            results.addAll(combinationsUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r));
        }
        return results;
    }

    // The main function that gets all combinations of size r
    // in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
    public static List<int[]> getAllCombinations(int[] arr, int n, int r)
    {
        return combinationsUtil(arr, new int[r], 0, n-1, 0, r);
    }

    public static long toLong(int[] ticket)
    {
        long l=0;
        for (int i=0; i<LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            l*=LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER;
            l+=ticket[i];
        }
        return l;
    }
    public static int[] fromLong(long l)
    {
        int[] result = new int[LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH];
        for (int i=LOTTERY_ROW_LENGTH-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            result[i] = (int) (((l % LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER) + LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER) % LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER);
            l/=LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static long[] generateTicketArray(List<int[]> allTickets) {
        System.out.println("Initializing arrays");
        long[] longTickets = new long[OPTIONS];
        for (int i=0; i<OPTIONS; i++) {
            int[] tic = allTickets.get(i);
            //System.out.println("Generating ticket:" + Arrays.toString(tic));

            long ticket = toLong(tic);
            longTickets[i] = ticket;
            //System.out.println("Generating ticket:" + longTickets[i]);
        }
        //Because the allTickets and toLong keep correct order, we don't need to sort :)

        return longTickets;
    }

    private static List<int[]> generateAllTickets() {
        System.out.println("Generating all options");

        int arr[] = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,LOTTERY_MAXIMUM_NUMBER).toArray();
        int r = 7;
        int n = arr.length;

        List<int[]> allTickets = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        allTickets = getAllCombinations(arr, n, r);
        return allTickets;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();

        //generate all valid tickets
        List<int[]> allTickets = generateAllTickets();


        long[] longTickets = generateTicketArray(allTickets);
        boolean[] soldTickets = new boolean[longTickets.length];

        System.out.println("Picking random tickets");

        for (int i=0; i<LOTTERY_ROWS; i++)
        {
            long randomTicket = toLong(allTickets.get(random.nextInt(OPTIONS)));
//           long randomTicket = toLong(allTickets.get(i % OPTIONS));

            //Use binary search on the sorted long array
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(longTickets, randomTicket);

            //If we have a valid index; mark the index as SOLD
            if (index>=0)
            {
                soldTickets[index] = true;
            }
            if (i%1_000_000 ==0)
            System.out.println("Picking random tickets, " + i);
        }

        System.out.println("Printing evil tickets");
        int evilTickets = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<OPTIONS; i++)
        {

            if (soldTickets[i] == false)
            {
                evilTickets++;
                //System.out.println("Evil ticket:" + Arrays.toString(fromLong(longTickets[i])));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("We have # Evil tickets:" + evilTickets);
    }



}
```